# Getting 403 when Azure REST API for blob storage with query strings having prefix or marker

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to use the Azure REST API for blob storage, and am using the AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-rest-api-with-auth to make the authorization header.

If I do this:

```
private static void DoItViaRest(string containerName, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        string uri = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list", STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, containerName);
        byte[] requestPayload = null;
        string xmlString = CallStorageRESTAPI(uri, requestPayload, log).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // handle exception
    }

    private static async Task<string> CallStorageRESTAPI(string uri, byte[] requestPayload, ILogger log)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri) { Content = (requestPayload == null) ? null : new ByteArrayContent(requestPayload) })
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R"));
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-07-29");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY, now, httpRequestMessage);
            using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
            {
                if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    log.LogInformation(string.Format("REST returned {0}", httpResponseMessage.StatusCode.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

then the authorization created by AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY, now, httpRequestMessage) works fine.

However if I add prefix or marker to the URI's query string, then I end up with a 403.
Examples with prefix:
https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list&prefix={2}
https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&prefix={2}&comp=list
Examples with marker:
https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list&marker={2}
https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&marker={2}&comp=list

The marker value above is the NextMarker returned from the original call.

I am a loss for what's wrong or how to fix it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have discovered an issue with the code in the Github repo.

Essentially the problem is coming because of the following lines of code:

```
    foreach (var item in values.AllKeys.OrderBy(k => k))
    {
        sb.Append('\n').Append(item).Append(':').Append(values[item]);
    }

    return sb.ToString().ToLower();
```

Essentially what this code is doing is taking all the query string parameters (name and value) and appending them in `name:value` format and then finally converting the entire string to lowercase (and that's the problem).

According to [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key), one should only be converting the key name to lowercase and not the value portion.

[image]

To fix this issue, please use the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This part of the signature string represents the storage account 
    ///   targeted by the request. Will also include any additional query parameters/values.
    /// For ListContainers, this will return something like this:
    ///   /storageaccountname/\ncomp:list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address">The URI of the storage service.</param>
    /// <param name="accountName">The storage account name.</param>
    /// <returns>String representing the canonicalized resource.</returns>
    private static string GetCanonicalizedResource(Uri address, string storageAccountName)
    {
        // The absolute path is "/" because for we're getting a list of containers.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/").Append(storageAccountName).Append(address.AbsolutePath);

        // Address.Query is the resource, such as "?comp=list".
        // This ends up with a NameValueCollection with 1 entry having key=comp, value=list.
        // It will have more entries if you have more query parameters.
        NameValueCollection values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(address.Query);

        foreach (var item in values.AllKeys.OrderBy(k => k))
        {
            sb.Append('\n').Append(item.ToLower()).Append(':').Append(values[item]);
        }

        return sb.ToString();//We should not be converting entire thing to lower case.
    }
```

However, please note that this is not still 100% correct as it doesn't take into consideration point #9 mentioned in the screenshot above but for your purpose it should work.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks much. I don't know how many hours I stared at the output and never noticed the marker value was lower cased.